# Embedding Chrome browser in python QT GUI?

Tags: python, selenium, pyqt4, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python GUI that opens a Chrome window using Seleium. Is there any way in the PyQT GUI to embed the Chrome browser's window so there are not 2 separate windows and its just the GUI? Guessing not possible but worth it to ask.

Comment: I am looking similar. Did you get the answer?

Comment: How do you application work? Do you have a minimal example showing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking to do exactly the same.  I don't have a complete answer but hopefully some of what I found will be of use to others who are trying to do this as well.

It IS possible to embed the window of an outside application into a Python QT application.  While I could quote various reference pages I have found that the following question gives most of the information and a good starting point to find more:

[QT 5.5 embed external application into QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699258/qt-5-5-embed-external-application-into-qwidget)

Now, that requires knowing the Window ID but that isn't too hard to find.  You can do that in Windows at least as described here:

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/find-the-window-for-my-subprocess.html

As I said, this isn't a complete answer but should put anyone else following this trail several steps closer to the complete answer.  Good luck everyone and if you find the complete answer please share it.