# Embed an external program in a window [Qt]

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I want to embed an external program within a qt application. I start the program by running a bash script. Running it works.

The script then opens two windows which I would like to embed in a window within the qt application GUI (all in one application). Is there a way to do this?
I have no knowledge of how the external application was made (i.e., I don't know if it was created with qt or not). I am working in Ubuntu 14.04.

Here's how I start the program:

```
QProcess *source = new QProcess(this);
const QString dir_source = "/path/to/script";
source->setWorkingDirectory(dir_source);

QStringList args;
args << "-wid" << QString::number(ui->sim->winId()); 
// sim is a widget name - this approach yields not result
source->setArguments(args);

source->start("./run.bash");
```

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699258/qt-5-5-embed-external-application-into-qwidget

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT 5.5 embed external application into QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699258/qt-5-5-embed-external-application-into-qwidget)