# Can i run external program using push button in widget inside of qt window?

Tags: qt, qt5

I am using qt creator to make ui on windows 10.

I want to run external program using push button and to place in widget inside of qt window. Now, I create the code to run external program when I click push button, but the program just appears outside qt window. Can I run external program using push button inside of qt window and set up the location where i want? I also upload my ui portion together.

[image]

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_8_clicked()    
{    
    QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
    QString file("D:\\My external file name");
    process->execute(file);
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///"+file,QUrl::TolerantMode));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT 5.5 embed external application into QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699258/qt-5-5-embed-external-application-into-qwidget)