# Embed terminal in QT Application

Tags: c++, macos, qt, terminal

I'm trying to find a way to embed a terminal application into my mac QT Application via a QTWidget. There are multiple applications which I want to embed, for example `ssh user@some_host -t "sudo htop"` or `ssh user@some_host -t "journalctl -u SomeService"`. The last command would be easy to embed into a text label, or something like that. But there would be the problem that the command outputs colors.

`htop` would be more problematic to embed, as it redraws the screen every second and uses a real terminal.

I have already tried the following things, but with no success.

- I wasn't able to compile any lib out of that thread: https://forum.qt.io/topic/6468/embedded-console-in-qt-gui
- This code is running fine, but doesn't print anything:

  ````
  proc.start("/usr/local/bin/htop");

  usleep(2000000);
  QProcess kill;
  kill.start("/usr/bin/killall htop");
  kill.waitForFinished();

  usleep(1000000);

  QByteArray buf = proc.readAllStandardOutput();

  cout << buf.toStdString() << endl;```
  ````

Another solution would be to embed the real terminal application, like shown here: [QT 5.5 embed external application into QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699258/qt-5-5-embed-external-application-into-qwidget)
Here the problem was that I can't get the right window id.

What do you think would be the better solution? Creating a custom QWidget or embedding an external application and how could I accomplish that?

Comment: If you have the id of a QWidget into which you want to embed a terminal then most terminal apps have some option allowing them to be embedded within that window: e.g. `xterm -into <winid>`  or `urxvt -embed <winid>` etc.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that is possible. As I use macOS, I think they use different schemes for windowIDs, as the error states: `xterm: invalid window-id 14022150102860`. So sadly, it doesn't work.